# Better way to use flash() in CFWheels?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfwheels

Using the `flash()` in CFWheels is pretty straight-forward, but I'm at a point where I need to insert more than just one simple message. If I do 3 `flashInsert()` calls, only the last one ever gets shown in the output of `flash()`.

As a work-around, I came up with this:

```
public void function index() {

        local.messages = [];

        arrayAppend(local.messages, { message="Test message 1.", type="ok" } );
        arrayAppend(local.messages, { message="Test message 2.", type="ok" } );
        arrayAppend(local.messages, { message="Test message 3.", type="ok" } );

        flashInsert( local.messages );

        WriteDump(var=flash(), abort=true);

    }
```

This way, I can then loop the flash() as an array in its object...accessing the message and type key's on each.

But, you know what? This feels dirty! And, repeating this for every action that I need it in seems like I'm breaking this holy DRY principle.

I've looked at as many related functions as I can regarding the flash, but nothing seems to acheive this output.

I also have the benefit here of specifying as many keys as I want in this message object...which is nice, as it can help with the output HTML.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on this...

Mikey.

Answer (score 0):

The flash is a struct, not an array. So if you do this...

```
flashInsert(message="Hi!");
flashInsert(message="Bye!");
```

...then the `message` key in the flash struct is going to get overwritten by the 2nd `flashInsert` call.

The most obvious solution would be to use different key names if you need multiple flash messages.

Is there a reason why they'd all need to share the same key name (`message` in this case)?

Comment: The flash is great for basic messaging, but with a more complex controller that fires off several things based on user input, it would be nice to have a few messages, dynamically placed in. I would then just be able to loop the messages. I have a work-around which I will post above...but it still feels a bit 'dirty'. In my loop, I don't want to be guessing key names, I just want to loop it and leave it.

Comment: I have just submit my own answer - have a look and see what you think?!

Comment: `flashMessages` kind of does what you're looking for. Have you looked into that? http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/flashmessages Note that the first argument is optional.

Comment: That almost looks like what I need! However, I haven't test it yet, but I assume you can't specify 2 keys with the same name? Will it overwrite it?

Comment: If only it was an array of structs! Which is what I guess I am trying to achieve. Either way, my method seems to work well. Would just rather use the CFWheels may, but in this case, it's not possible. Thanks for your help though Chris!

Answer (score 0):

I never found anything built in to do what I want, but I rolled my own solution.

Not sure if there are potential problems here, but it seems to work great. Would be nice to get people's opinions on doing it this way.

**Controller.cfc**

```
component extends="Wheels" output="false" {

    messages = [];

    public any function init() { }


    public void function addMessage(object) {

        arrayAppend(messages, arguments.object);

    }


    public void function insertMessages() {

        local.messages = messages;
        flashInsert( messages = local.messages );

        return;

    } 

}
```

**User.cfc**

```
component extends="Controller" output="false" {     

        public void function index() {

            super.addMessage({ message="Example message 1.", type="ok" });
            super.addMessage({ message="Example message 2.", type="info" });
            super.addMessage({ message="Example message 3.", type="error" });
            super.insertMessages();

        }

}
```

**View (loops the flash)**

```
<cfset variables.flash = flash() />

<cfif not structIsEmpty(variables.flash)>

    <div id="messages">

        <cfoutput>

            <cfloop array="#variables.flash.messages#" index="variables.i">
                <p class="alert alert-#variables.i.type#">
                    #variables.i.message#
                </p>
            </cfloop>

        </cfoutput>

    </div>

</cfif>
```

Any idea's on this doing it with this technique?

:)